# Jenkins Active Choices Parameter plugin not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a `hidden parameter` in `Jenkins` called `platformType`. I want to display choices based on the parameter `platformType`. I created the following groovy script but it doesn't work

```
if (platformType.equals("android")) {
  return ['7.0', '6.0']
} else (platformType.equals("ios")) {
  return ['10.0', '9.0']
}
```

Pls see the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

quite sure you did not specify the `platformType` as a parameter to `platformVersion` or you have other error in your code..

without error handling you just don't see it.

in your script you can catch the exception like this:

```
try {
    if (platformType.equals("android")) {
        return ['7.0', '6.0']
    } else if(platformType.equals("ios")) {
        return ['10.0', '9.0']
    }
}catch(e){ return [e.toString()] }
```

in this case you'll see the error in your choice field

Comment: How do I specify platformType as parameter to platformVersion?

Comment: Ok it says `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: platformType for class: Script1`

Comment: use `Active Choices Reactive Parameter` and specify for it the `Referenced parameters = platformType`

Comment: Awesome!, Though its not a good practice to show error in choice parameter, helped me to find the actual error in my case

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are missing `if` in the else part.

It is supposed to be:

```
if ('android' == platformType) {
  return ['7.0', '6.0']
} else if ('ios' == platformType) {
  return ['10.0', '9.0']
} else return []
```

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't show any error. Pls see my response to @daggett